# Is there a Flutter StreamBuilder which allows me to listen to multiple streams?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a StreamBuilder which allows me to listen to multiple streams?
something like:

```
   body: MultiStreamBuilder(
        streams: [bloc.state.stream, bloc.kind.stream],
        builder: (context) {
```

I don't need the snapshot like in the Flutter StreamBuilder because I can just read from the bloc

Comment: you can use `rx-dart`'s `Observable` [static methods](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable-class.html#static-methods) for that

Comment: Can u post an example

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/combineLatest2.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is updating the UI (calling build) whenever one of the streams gets updates. I don't use the snapshot.data because I am reading the data directly from the bloc and snapshot.data contains only a bool not the real data of the streams.

```
class _RemoteDebuggingScreenState extends State<RemoteDebuggingScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    RemoteDebugBlog bloc = BlocProvider.of(context).remoteDebugBloc;

    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Observable.combineLatest2(bloc.state.stream, bloc.kind.stream,
            (b1, b2) => b1 != null || b2 != null),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();

          return Column(...
```

for more info with some nice graphics about `combineLatest` check this out:
https://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/rxdart-magical-transformations-of-streams/

Now knowing the above I moved this into a Widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class DoubleStreamBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  DoubleStreamBuilder(
      {@required this.stream1, @required this.stream2, @required this.builder});

  final Stream stream1;
  final Stream stream2;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext) builder;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) => StreamBuilder(
      stream: Rx.combineLatest2(
          stream1, stream2, (b1, b2) => b1 != null || b2 != null),
      builder: (context, snapshot) => builder(context));
}
```

The usage is now clear and simple like this:

```
 return DoubleStreamBuilder(
    stream1: settingsBloc.uiVin.stream,
    stream2: settingsBloc.isPseudoVin.stream,
    builder: (context) {
   => this updates when stream 1 or 2 have new values
   }
```

Comment: snapshot.data == null is not necessary because !snapshot.hasData is the same.

Comment: Observable is deprecated in RxDart 0.23.1
You can now use the abstract class Rx such as `Rx.combineLatest2`